# "Illegal characters in path" error using MemoryStream

Tags: c#, file, directory, memorystream, illegal-characters

I am going in circles with this. But all I am doing is, reading a simple text file into a byte array and reading a byte array into memory stream. Take a look at the code below.

```
var filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\TextFile1.txt";
var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(fileContent)) {}
```

And I get an error "Illegal characters in path".

Here is my text file content:

ASJJDASDA

ASDJKAJSDJKASJDKLASJD

ASDASDASD++++++++++

++++++++

Any ideas?

Comment: _"Illegal characters in path"_ is usually an IO error. What's the value of `filePath` and what line do you get the error on?

Comment: @MasterYoda what's the difference to the line OP already uses?

Comment: I dont see this being an issue with the memory stream, if he gets the current directory \\ will go down another directory whereas \ will stay within the current one. FYI i dont know where OP stores his textfile, its a suggestion not an answer...

Comment: @MasterYoda now it won't compile because `\T` is not a valid escape character. If you mean `@"\TextFile1.txt"` we're at the starting point again, it's the same. But you're right, something must be wrong with the path.

Comment: You can use [Path.Combine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) here to make your intentions clearer (and avoid the apparent confusion of how to use escape codes).

Comment: @RenéVogt It will compile just fine. It just won't work as expected.

Comment: Please verify the value of `filePath`. I somehow doubt that this is all the relevant code, because `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` must return a valid path with no trailing `\\` (and even that would not matter). So the code seems correct so far.

Comment: Print the value of filePath please and update your question. The problem has to have something to do with the filePath string and how its being escaped.

Comment: @itsme86 don't know your compiler, but mine raises an error on "Unrecognized esacpe sequence"s.

Comment: OP's code works fine for me. As others have said, it would be handy to see what filePath contains.

Comment: I get a valid full path too.

Comment: @RenéVogt You're correct. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

The above example should work.

Is it possible you have a weird instance where there is a backslash at the end of the Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()?

Try substituting

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "TextFile1.txt");
```

and see what happens then.